# Storing gmail messages on backend server

Tags: email, google-api, gmail, privacy, gmail-imap

Lets say i have an android app that has google login and lets the backend app (via token exchanges) to read the user's inbox. Is it allowed to store these messages on the backend for caching purpose ? If not , whats the best way, considering the rate limits ?

How does [Tripit](https://www.tripit.com/) or even boomerang do that?

Thanks